# yii2 - two modal in one active form

Tags: yii2, modal-dialog

I have 2 modals in one active form. Let's say first one is modal-ticket and second one is contract-ticket. First time, I click button to show modal-ticket, and it was fine, but when I click button to show modal-contract, it also call script modal-ticket or otherwise. why?

this is my code.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div id="BtnSearchTicket">
    <?= Html::button('Search Ticket', [
        'value' => Url::to('../ticket-timbangan/list'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'id' => 'BtnModalTicketList',
        'data-toggle'=>"modal",
        'data-target'=>"#modalTicketList",
    ]) ?>
</div>

<div id="BtnSearchContract">
    <?= Html::button('Search Contract', [
        'value' => Url::to('../contract/list'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'id' => 'BtnModalContractList',
        'data-toggle'=>"modal",
        'data-target'=>"#modalContractList",
    ]) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'header' => 'Ticket List',
        'id' => 'modalTicketList',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        'class' => 'style=width:auto'
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContentTicket'></div>";
    Modal::end();
?>
<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'header' => 'Contract List',
        'id' => 'modalContractList',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        'class' => 'style=width:auto'
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContentContract'></div>";
    Modal::end();
?>

<?php
$script = <<< JS
$('#BtnModalTicketList').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modalTicketList').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContentTicket')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
   return false;
});

$('#BtnModalContractList').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modalContractList').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContentContract')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
   return false;
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

this are the error found in console web browser

```
GET http://localhost/pks/web/ticket-timbangan/get-ticket?id=1 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/pks/web/contract/get-contract?id=2 404 (Not Found)
```

please help.

Comment: Why are you using two modals  on the same form.

Comment: it's the requirement to search for ticket and contract.

Comment: i assume at one point  you search for either one or are the searches related.

Comment: this two modal not related, they are two different data. they are just reference to this new data input.

Comment: Try my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, many thanks to [kalu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6285656/kalu) who has helped me 2 days to solve my problem. Two modals which contains grid need to define different classes to prevent execute previous script.
`'value' => Url::to('../ticket-timbangan/list')` and `'value' => Url::to('../contract/list'),` both has two gridview and same `select-row` class. This class is root cause of the problem, because it's same class and execute both script.
Thanks Kalu, you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: using one modal on your form:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div id="BtnSearchTicket">
    <?= Html::button('Search Ticket', [
        'value' => Url::to('../ticket-timbangan/list'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary showModal',
        'id' => 'BtnModalTicketList',
        'title' => 'Search Ticket',
    ]) ?>
</div>

<div id="BtnSearchContract">
    <?= Html::button('Search Contract', [
        'value' => Url::to('../contract/list'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary showModal',
        'title' => 'Search Contract',
        'id' => 'BtnModalContractList',
    ]) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        'closeButton' => [
            'id'=>'close-button',
            'class'=>'close',
            'data-dismiss' =>'modal',
            ],
        'class' => 'style=width:auto',
        'clientOptions' => [
        'backdrop' => false, 'keyboard' => true
        ]
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    Modal::end();
?>

<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).on('click', '.showModal', function(){

        if ($('#modal').hasClass('in')) {
            $('#modal').find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
            document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        } else {
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
            document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        }
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried it. but cannot show the modal at all.

Comment: This should work. Just tested it. you just have to change enter the correct url in `Url::to('some-controller/some-action')`

Comment: i have tested. still don't show the modal. if `Url::to('some-controller/some-action')` or `Url::to('some-controller/some-action')`, it will directly go to this controller's view not exact controller. I using `..` in order to go back one path to find exact controller. let's say now i work with pengiriman-produksi controller and my modal will show ticket-timbangan or contract controller with action list. if i do not put `..` it will directly go to `GET http://localhost/pks/web/pengiriman-produksi/ticket-timbangan/list 404 (Not Found)` . it should `http://localhost/pks/web/ticket-timbangan/list`

Comment: here is my work. you can see what's going wrong [code](https://pastebin.com/fDFPxMVB)

Comment: please share what you have after the changes

Comment: ok. I miss class showModal so it doesn't show up. the title is undefined and in contract list or ticket list, i hide the modal using `$('#modal').modal('hide');` after select data what user want. The result is as  same as old one. still execute first modal.

Comment: for the title add `'title' => 'Search Contract'` in your html::button options

Comment: ok thanks. but the result is same as my old way. still execute the first one user click. here the [image](https://imgur.com/a/fO1f4) i share.

Comment: check your js code. especially any on-click event handlers you have for thise buttons

Comment: strange. what are the `'value'=> ...` of your two buttons?

Comment: `public function actionGetTicket($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        return Json::encode($model);
    }`
I return model

Comment: i observe every time i call the modal, it execute as many as the user open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

From viewing your code what calls my attention is how you use the `Url::to()` function. Not sure why you use `../`. I have fiddled with using more than one modal in a form and the code is similar to what your are doing. I suggest you try changing your `Url::to()` function as follows:

```
Url::to('/ticket-timbangan/list')
```

and

```
Url::to('/contract/list')
```

Another suggestion would be to try with

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/ticket-timbangan/list')
```

and

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/contract/list')
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Url::to does not work because it stay at current controller and the result would be current-controller/contract/list (NOT FOUND). `Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl()` it works.